# How can I create a computational function based on checkboxes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have several checkboxes in my table (unspecified number) and set a value of `2000` for each checkbox.
I want each check box that was checked to be multiplied by `2000` and if it was unchecked `2000` be deducted from the total amount?

For example, if 3 checkboxes are checked, the number 3 is multiplied by `2000` ,`3 * 2000`.
And if it is unchecked from this number, its value will be deducted from the total?

And display the total value in `span`?

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>             
        <th>
           choose
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in listitem)
    {
        <tr>                                                 
           
            <td>
                <input class="check-horse mr-2" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" />
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

```
total price :<span class="text-success totalprice"></span>
```

Comment: Isn't `@foreach (var item in listitem) {...}` #C?

Comment: @zer00ne yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the checked checkbox simply by using `:checked` pseudo selector

```
const multiplier = 2000;
function getTotalPrice(){
    const checkedCount = $('.check-horse:checked').length;
    return checkedCount * multiplier;
}

$(document).on('change','.check-horse', e=> $('.totalprice').text(getTotalPrice());
```

It should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Details are commented in example below. Note, the value of each checkbox has been assigned as 2000. Also instead of a `<span>`, an `<output>` is used -- it is an inline tag and can contain text like a `<span>`, but unlike the `<span>` an `<output>` can also have a `value` like a form-control (ex. `<input>`, `<select>`, etc.).

```js
/*
Whenever the user changes the state of any checkbox the event
handler chkSum(e) is invoked
*/
$(':checkbox').on('change', chkSum);

// Event handler is a function that listens for events
function chkSum(e) {
  // Define a 0 value in outer scope
  let total = 0;
  // On each checkbox that's CHECKED...
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    // Add the checkbox value (converted into a real number) to total
    total += Number($(this).val());
  });
  /* 
  After iterations display total value 
  output.total can also use .val()
  */
  $('.total').text(total);
};
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <output class='total'>0</output><br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='2000'><br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='2000'><br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='2000'><br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='2000'><br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='2000'><br>
  <input type='checkbox' value='2000'><br>
</fieldset>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```